# Add and manage Product custom upload field in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, file-upload, woocommerce

I am trying to add a file upload along with radio inputs in a custom woocommerce page; where all the products are showing in a list view.

**The Custom Page CODE:**

```
        <?php /*
    Template Name: Custom Woo Product List Page
    */ ?>
    <?php get_header();?>


          <div class="inn_page">


                <table id="wh_table" class="table table-hover" width="100%" cellspacing="0">

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>PRODUCT</th>
                    <th>Monogram letter or Message Box</th>
                    <th>PRICE</th>              
                    <th>Product Total Quantity</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>

                    <tbody>         
                    <?php
                        $args = array( 
                        'post_type' => array('product', 'product_variation'), 
                        'post_status' => array('publish'),
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'product_cat' => '', 
                        'post__in' => array( 178, 39, 180, 101, 182, 108, 184, 171, 872, 877, 206, 197, 1028, 330, 216, 451, 481, 478, 589 ),
                        'orderby' => 'post__in',
                        //'order'     => 'DESC',
                        'paged'   => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1 );
                        $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
                        global $product; 
                    ?>

                    <?php if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) 
                        {   
                            show_variable_products_list();              
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                    ?>

                    <tr class="product-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?> variations_form" data-role="product"> 
                    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" name="upload_form" id="upload_form" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $wp_query->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($wp_query->post->post_title ? $wp_query->post->post_title : $wp_query->post->ID); ?>">

                            <td class="image">

                                <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $wp_query->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($wp_query->post->ID, 'wh_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="150px" height="150px" />'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="title">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <?php if ( ($product->get_id() == 178) || ($product->get_id() == 589) ) { ?>
                                    <b>Sterling Silver</b>
                                <?php } ?>                      
                            </td>

                            <td class="note">                           
                                <?php letter_note(); ?>
                                <?php msg_note(); ?>
                                <?php upload_logo(); ?>         
                            </td>

                            <td class="wh-price">
                                <span class="hiddenPrice"><?php echo $product->get_price_html() ?></span>
                                <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount ajaxPrice"><?php echo $product->get_price_html() ?></span>
                            </td>

                        </a>

                            <td class="quantity-field">
                                <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
                            </td>

                            <td class="button-row">
                                <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />
                                <div class="wh-button">
                                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-primary button wh-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> ADD TO CART</button>
                                </div>


                            </td>


                    </form>

                    </tr>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        </tbody>

                </table><!--/.products-->

            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>              


          </div>



    <?php get_footer();?>
```

**For variations to show in list view as different items/products in funtions.php**

```
        <?php 

        //----------------------------- START PRODUCT LIST VIEW PAGE CODE ----------------------------------

        //-------------------------------------- Variations in Table List  ---------------------------

        function show_variable_products_list(){
            global $product, $post;

            $variations = find_valid_variations();

            asort($variations);

                    foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
                        if( !$value['variation_is_visible'] ) continue; ?>

                    <?php 
                    $id_variation = $value['variation_id']          
                    ?>
                    <tr class="product-<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?> variation-<?php echo $value['variation_id']?> variations_form" data-role="product"> 
                      <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">  
                        <td class="image">
                            <?php echo '<img src="'.$value['image_src'].'" alt="'.$product->get_title().'-'.$value['variation_id'].'" width="150px" height="150px" />'; ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="title">
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3><br />
                            <b class="var-name"><?php                   
                            foreach($value['attributes'] as $attr_name => $attr_value ) {
                            $attr_name = 'pa_setting';
                            $attr = get_term_by('slug', $attr_value, $attr_name);
                            $attr_value = $attr->name;
                            echo $attr_value, '  ';                 
                            } 
                            ?></b>
                            <?php echo $id_variation ?>
                        </td>

                        <td class="note">
                            <?php letter_note(); ?>
                            <?php msg_note(); ?>
                            <?php upload_logo(); ?>
                        </td>   
                        <td class="wh-price">
                            <span class="hiddenPrice"><?php echo $value['price_html'];?></span>
                            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount ajaxPrice"><?php echo $value['price_html'];?></span>
                        </td>


                            <?php if( $value['is_in_stock'] ) { ?>


                            <td class="quantity-field">
                                <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>                      
                            </td>

                            <td class="button-row">
                                <?php
                                if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                                    foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                                    ?>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                                    <?php
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                                <div class="wh-button">
                                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button btn btn-primary button wh-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> ADD TO CART</button>
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />

                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
                            <?php } ?>

                            </td>
                            </form>

                            </tr>

                    <?php 
                    } 
                    } 

                    ?>


        <?php

        function find_valid_variations() {
            global $product;
        if ( $product->get_id() == 330 ) {


            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            //$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            $new_variants = array();

          /* Show only the variations listed below */
            foreach( $variations as $variation ) {
         if ( $variation["variation_id"] == 971 || $variation["variation_id"] == 958 || $variation["variation_id"] == 945 || $variation["variation_id"] == 422 || $variation["variation_id"] == 412 || $variation["variation_id"] == 386 || $variation["variation_id"] == 358 ) {

                $valid = true; 

                if( $valid )
                    $new_variants[] = $variation;
            }       
            }


        }
        elseif ( $product->get_id() == 216 ) {


            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $new_variants = array();


            foreach( $variations as $variation ) {
         if ( $variation["variation_id"] == 1010 || $variation["variation_id"] == 997 || $variation["variation_id"] == 984 || $variation["variation_id"] == 321 || $variation["variation_id"] == 295 || $variation["variation_id"] == 267 || $variation["variation_id"] == 237 ) {

                $valid = true; 

                if( $valid )
                    $new_variants[] = $variation;
            }       
            }


        }

        else {


            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
            $new_variants = array();


            foreach( $variations as $variation ) {

                $valid = true; 
                foreach( $attributes as $slug => $args ) {
                    if( array_key_exists("attribute_$slug", $variation['attributes']) && !empty($variation['attributes']["attribute_$slug"]) ) {
                        // Exists

                    } else {

                        $valid = false; 

                        foreach( explode( '|', $attributes[$slug]['value']) as $attribute ) {
                            $attribute = trim( $attribute );
                            $new_variant = $variation;
                            $new_variant['attributes']["attribute_$slug"] = $attribute;
                            $new_variants[] = $new_variant;

                        }

                    }
                }

                if( $valid )
                    $new_variants[] = $variation;

            }
        } 
            return $new_variants;
        }           

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart', 'show_variable_products_list', 10, 2 );


        ?>
```

I am able to add the radio values to cart & order but not able to do anything with file upload.

Please take a look:

```
    add_action("woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button", "upload_logo", 9);
    function upload_logo(){
        ?>
        <div>
            <p>Want to add Logo? <input type="checkbox" id="showHide"  onclick="myFunction()"><b>Tick</b></p>

    <p id="hiddenInputs" style="display:none">
            <label for="radio_field">
                Where you want the logo?
                <input type="radio" name="radio_field" checked="checked" value="Front Side"> Front Side
                <input type="radio" name="radio_field" value="Back Side"> Back Side
                <input type="radio" name="radio_field" value="Both Side"> Both Side
            </label> <br />

            <label for="file_field">
                Upload logo: <input type="file" name="file_field" value="">
            </label> <br />
    </p>
    </div>


    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        var checkboxToShowInputs = document.getElementById("showHide");
        var showInputs = document.getElementById("hiddenInputs");
        if (checkboxToShowInputs.checked == true){
            showInputs.style.display = "block";
        } else {
           showInputs.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>

        <?php
    }

    /* Add File custom data to the cart item */

    function file_upload_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

        if( isset( $_POST['file_field'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['logo_upload'] = $_POST['file_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'file_upload_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );

     /* Add Radio custom data to the cart item */
     // Stores the custom field value in Cart object
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_product_field_data', 10, 2 );
    function save_custom_product_field_data( $cart_item, $product_id ) {
        if( isset( $_REQUEST['radio_field'] ) ) {
            $cart_item[ 'side_radio' ] = $_REQUEST['radio_field'];
            // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
            $cart_item['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
            WC()->session->set( 'my_order_data', $_REQUEST['radio_field'] );
        }
        return $cart_item;
    }


    /* Load File cart data from session */

    function file_upload_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

        if ( isset( $values['logo_upload'] ) ){
            $cart_item['logo_upload'] = $values['logo_upload'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'file_upload_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2 );


    /* Load Radio cart data from session */

    function radio_get_cart_item_from_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

        if ( isset( $values['side_radio'] ) ){
            $cart_item['side_radio'] = $values['side_radio'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'radio_get_cart_item_from_session', 20, 2 );


    /* Add File meta to order item */

    function file_upload_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

        if ( ! empty( $values['logo_upload'] ) ) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'logo_upload', $values['logo_upload'] );           
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'file_upload_add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );

    /* Add Radio meta to order item */

    function radio_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

        if ( ! empty( $values['side_radio'] ) ) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'side_radio', $values['side_radio'] );           
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'radio_add_order_item_meta', 10, 2 );


    /* Get File item data to display in cart */

    function file_upload_get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

        if ( ! empty ( $cart_item['logo_upload'] ) ){

            $other_data[] = array(
                'name' => __( 'Logo ', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' =>  $cart_item['logo_upload']
            );

        }

        return $other_data;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'file_upload_get_item_data', 10, 2 );

    /* Get Radio item data to display in cart */

    function radio_get_item_data( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

        if ( ! empty ( $cart_item['side_radio'] ) ){

            $other_data[] = array(
                'name' => __( 'Side ', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' =>  $cart_item['side_radio']
            );

        }

        return $other_data;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'radio_get_item_data', 10, 2 );


    /* Show File field in order overview */

    function file_upload_order_item_product( $cart_item, $order_item ){

        if( isset( $order_item['logo_upload'] ) ){
            $cart_item_meta['logo_upload'] = $order_item['logo_upload'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', 'file_upload_order_item_product', 10, 2 );


    /* Show Radio field in order overview */

    function radio_order_item_product( $cart_item, $order_item ){

        if( isset( $order_item['side_radio'] ) ){
            $cart_item_meta['side_radio'] = $order_item['side_radio'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', 'radio_order_item_product', 10, 2 );


    /* Add the File Upload field to order emails */ 

    function file_upload_email_order_meta_fields( $fields ) { 
        $fields['custom_field'] = __( 'Logo ', 'woocommerce' ); 
        return $fields; 
    } 
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'file_upload_email_order_meta_fields');

    /* Add the Radio field to order emails */ 

    function radio_email_order_meta_fields( $fields ) { 
        $fields['custom_field'] = __( 'Side ', 'woocommerce' ); 
        return $fields; 
    } 
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'radio_email_order_meta_fields');
```

**Here's the AJAX PHP**

```
        function ajax_add_to_cart_script() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'add-to-cart-wh_ajax', plugins_url() . '/wh-page-ajax-add-to-cart/js/add-to-cart-wh.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_add_to_cart_script',99 );

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_to_cart_wh_sh', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_wh_sh_callback' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_add_to_cart_wh_sh', 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_wh_sh_callback' );

    function woocommerce_add_to_cart_wh_sh_callback() {

        ob_start();

        $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint( $_POST['product_id'] ) );
        $quantity = empty( $_POST['quantity'] ) ? 1 : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_stock_amount', $_POST['quantity'] );
        $variation_id = $_POST['variation_id'];
        $variation  = $_POST['variation'];          
        $letter = $_POST['_letter'];
        $message = $_POST['_message'];              
        $radio = $_POST['radio_field'];     
        //$file = $_POST['file_field'];
        $file = $_FILES['id_proof'];;       
        $passed_validation = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $quantity, $cart_item_data, $letter, $message, $radio, $file );

        if ( $passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $letter, $message, $radio, $file ) ) {
            do_action( 'woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id );
            if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) == 'yes' ) {
                wc_add_to_cart_message( $product_id );
            }

            // Return fragments
            WC_AJAX::get_refreshed_fragments();
        }  else {
            $this->json_headers();

            // If there was an error adding to the cart, redirect to the product page to show any errors
            $data = array(
                'error' => true,
                'product_url' => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink( $product_id ), $product_id )
                );
            echo json_encode( $data );
        }
        die();
    }
```

And here's the edited js

```
         /* AJAX Add to Cart Button */
    jQuery(function($) {

        // wc_add_to_cart_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
        if (typeof wc_add_to_cart_params === 'undefined')
            return false;

        // Ajax add to cart
        $(document).on('click', '.variations_form .wh-btn', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $variation_form = $(this).closest('.variations_form');
            var var_id = $variation_form.find('input[name=variation_id]').val();
            var product_id = $variation_form.find('input[name=product_id]').val();
            var quantity = $variation_form.find('input[name=quantity]').val();              
            var letter = $variation_form.find('input[name=_wholesale_letter]').val();
            var message = $variation_form.find('input[name=_wholesale_message]').val();
            var rad = $variation_form.find('input[name=radio_field]:checked').val();
            var file = $variation_form.find('input[name=file_field]').val();
            //var file = $variation_form.find('input[name=file_field]').files[0].path;

            //attributes = [];
            $('.ajaxerrors').remove();
            var item = {},
                check = true;

            variations = $variation_form.find('select[name^=attribute]');

            /* Updated code to work with radio button - mantish - WC Variations Radio Buttons - 8manos */
            if (!variations.length) {
                variations = $variation_form.find('[name^=attribute]:checked');
            }

            /* Backup Code for getting input variable */
            if (!variations.length) {
                variations = $variation_form.find('input[name^=attribute]');
            }

            variations.each(function() {

                var $this = $(this),
                    attributeName = $this.attr('name'),
                    attributevalue = $this.val(),
                    index,
                    attributeTaxName;

                $this.removeClass('has-error');

                if (attributevalue.length === 0) {
                    index = attributeName.lastIndexOf('_');
                    attributeTaxName = attributeName.substring(index + 1);

                    $this
                        //.css( 'border', '1px solid red' )
                        .addClass('required has-error')
                        //.addClass( 'barizi-class' )
                        .before('<div class="ajaxerrors"><p>OH No Please select ' + attributeTaxName + '</p></div>')

                    //check = false;
                } else {
                    item[attributeName] = attributevalue;
                }


            });

            if (!check) {
                return false;
            }

            /* Validate for All the input Message field */

            var itemMessages = {},
                checkmsg = true;
            messages = $variation_form.find('input[name=_message');


            messages.each(function() {

                var $this = $(this),
                    attributeName = $this.attr('name'),
                    attributevalue = $this.val(),
                    index,
                    attributeTaxName;

                $this.removeClass('required wh-error');

                if (attributevalue.length === 0) {
                    index = attributeName.lastIndexOf('_');
                    attributeTaxName = attributeName.substring(index + 1);

                    $this
                        .removeClass('wh-input')
                        .addClass('required wh-error')                              
                        .before('<div class="ajaxerrors"><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">REQUIRED!</span> Please Type Some Text or Number.</p></div>')

                    //checkmsg = false;
                } else {
                    itemMessages[attributeName] = attributevalue;
                    $this.addClass('wh-input');
                }


            });

            if (!checkmsg) {
                return false;
            }


            /* Validate One Letter Input Field */
            var itemLetter = {},
                checkltr = true;
            letterOne = $variation_form.find('input[name=_letter]');


            letterOne.each(function() {

                var $this = $(this),
                    attributeName = $this.attr('name'),
                    attributevalue = $this.val(),
                    index,
                    attributeTaxName;

                $this.removeClass('required wh-error');

                if (attributevalue.length === 0) {
                    index = attributeName.lastIndexOf('_');
                    attributeTaxName = attributeName.substring(index + 1);

                    $this
                       /* .css({
                        'border': '2px solid #a94442', 
                        'box-shadow': 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #ce8483'                            
                        })*/
                        .removeClass('wh-input')
                        .addClass('required wh-error')                          
                        .before('<div class="ajaxerrors"><p><span style="font-weight: bold;">REQUIRED!</span> Please Type 1 Letter or Number.</p></div>')

                    //checkmsg = false;
                } else {
                    itemLetter[attributeName] = attributevalue;
                    $this.addClass('wh-input');
                }


            });

            if (!checkltr) {
                return false;
            }


           //item = JSON.stringify(item);
            //alert(item);
            //return false;

            // AJAX add to cart request

            var $thisbutton = $(this);

            if ($thisbutton.is('.variations_form .wh-btn')) {

                $thisbutton.removeClass('added');
                $thisbutton.addClass('loading');
                $thisbutton.attr("disabled", "disabled");


                var data = {
                    action: 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_wh_sh',
                    product_id: product_id,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    variation_id: var_id,
                    variation: item,                        
                    _letter: letter,
                    _message: message,
                    radio_field: rad,
            file_field: file
                };

                $.each($thisbutton.data(), function(key, value) {
                    data[key] = value;
                });

                // Trigger event
                $('body').trigger('adding_to_cart', [$thisbutton, data]);

                // Ajax action
                $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function(response) {

                        if (!response) {
                            return;
                        }

                        var this_page = window.location.toString();

                        this_page = this_page.replace('add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart');

                        if (response.error && response.product_url) {
                            window.location = response.product_url;
                            return;
                        }

                        if (wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_redirect_after_add === 'yes') {

                            window.location = wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url;
                            return;

                        } else {

                            $thisbutton.removeClass('loading');

                            var fragments = response.fragments;
                            var cart_hash = response.cart_hash;

                            // Block fragments class
                            if (fragments) {
                                $.each(fragments, function(key) {
                                    $(key).addClass('updating');
                                });
                            }

                            // Block widgets and fragments
                            $('.shop_table.cart, .updating, .cart_totals').fadeTo('400', '0.6').block({
                                message: null,
                                overlayCSS: {
                                    opacity: 0.6
                                }
                            });

                            // Changes button classes
                            $thisbutton.addClass('added');

                            // View cart text
                            /*  if ( ! wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $thisbutton.parent().find( '.added_to_cart' ).size() === 0 ) {
                                    $thisbutton.after( ' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
                                        wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>' );
                                }

                            // View cart text
                            if (!wc_add_to_cart_params.is_cart && $variation_form.find('.added_to_cart').length === 0) {
                                $thisbutton.after(' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
                                    wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>');
                            }
                             */

                            // Replace fragments
                            if (fragments) {
                                $.each(fragments, function(key, value) {
                                    $(key).replaceWith(value);
                                });
                            }

                            // Unblock
                            $('.widget_shopping_cart, .updating').stop(true).css('opacity', '1').unblock();

                            // Cart page elements
                            $('.shop_table.cart').load(this_page + ' .shop_table.cart:eq(0) > *', function() {

                                $('.shop_table.cart').stop(true).css('opacity', '1').unblock();

                                $(document.body).trigger('cart_page_refreshed');
                            });

                            $('.cart_totals').load(this_page + ' .cart_totals:eq(0) > *', function() {
                                $('.cart_totals').stop(true).css('opacity', '1').unblock();
                            });

                            // Trigger event so themes can refresh other areas
                            $(document.body).trigger('added_to_cart', [fragments, cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
                        }
                    })
                    .done(function(response) {
                        if ($variation_form.find('.added_to_cart').length === 0) {
                            $thisbutton.after(' <a href="' + wc_add_to_cart_params.cart_url + '" class="added_to_cart wc-forward" title="' +
                                wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '">' + wc_add_to_cart_params.i18n_view_cart + '</a>');
                        }

                        $thisbutton.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");                         
                        $thisbutton.removeClass('failed')

                        var quantity = $variation_form.find('input[name=quantity]').val("1");
                        var letter = $variation_form.find('input[name=_letter]').val("");
                        var message = $variation_form.find('input[name=_message]').val("");
                        var rad = $variation_form.find('input[name=radio_field]').val("Front Side");
                    })
                    .fail(function(response) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $thisbutton.removeClass('loading');
                            $thisbutton.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }, 2000);
                        $thisbutton.addClass('failed');
                    })

                return false;

            } else {
                return true;
            }

        });

    });
```

This page is only accessible to certain users, so it has different input fields, price than the single product page counterpart. Client don't like this page to be refreshed so I had to add **AJAX**, with the little knowledge I have. Now it's getting more complicated so please help me out.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please take look now, I used **add-to-cart-variations.js** to make a really small plugin to help me out. Didn't change any core files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2021** - *Still works perfectly on last WooCommerce version (5.1.x)*.

In your actual code, there is many mistakes as:

- Repetitive hooked functions using the same hook, that need to be merged instead.
- Deprecated hooked functions.
- Not useful or not needed hooked functions.
- Wrong or **missing code related to file upload**

Here is your revisited code *(much more lighter, compact and complete)*:

```
// Display additional product fields (+ jQuery code)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_additional_product_fields', 9 );
function display_additional_product_fields(){
    // Array of radio button options
    $options = array( __("Front Side"), __("Back Side"), __("Both Sides") );
    // Temporary styles
    ?>
    <style>
    .upload-logo a.button { padding: .3em .75em !important; }
    .upload-logo a.button.on { background-color: #CC0000 !important; color: #FFFFFF !important; }
    .upload-logo p span { display:inline-block; padding:0 8px 0 4px; }
    </style><?php
    // Html output ?>
    <div class="upload-logo">
        <p><strong><?php _e( "Add a Logo option"); ?>: </strong>
            <a href="#" class="button"><?php _e( "Yes" ); ?></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="upload_active" value="">
        </p>
        <div id="hidden-inputs" style="display:none">
            <p><label for="radio_field"><?php

            echo __( "Where you want the logo?" ) . ' <br>';

            // Loop though each $options array
            foreach( $options as $key => $option ) {
                $atts = $key == 0 ? 'name="side_field" checked="checked"' : 'name="side_field"'; ?>
                <input type="radio" <?php echo $atts; ?> value="<?php echo $option; ?>"><span> <?php echo $option . '</span> ';
            }
            ?>
            </label></p>
            <p><label for="file_field"><?php echo __("Upload logo") . ': '; ?>
                <input type='file' name='image' accept='image/*'>
            </label></p>
        </div>
    </div><?php
    // Javascript (jQuery) ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        var a = '.upload-logo',         b = a+' a.button',
            c = a+' #hidden-inputs',    d = a+' input[type=hidden]';

        $(b).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if( ! $(this).hasClass('on') ) {
                $(this).addClass('on');
                $(c).show();
                $(d).val('1');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('on');
                $(c).hide('fast');
                $(d).val('');
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

// @ ===> Manage the file upload <=== @
// Add custom fields data as the cart item custom data 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_fields_data_as_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function add_custom_fields_data_as_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){
    if( isset($_POST['upload_active']) && $_POST['upload_active'] && isset($_FILES['image']) ) {
        $upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['image']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) );

        $filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );

        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

        $upl_base_url = is_ssl() ? str_replace('http://', 'https://', $upload_dir['baseurl']) : $upload_dir['baseurl'];

        $base_name = basename( $upload['file'] );

        $cart_item['custom_file'] = array(
            'guid'      => $upl_base_url .'/'. _wp_relative_upload_path( $upload['file'] ),
            'file_type' => $filetype['type'],
            'file_name' => $base_name,
            'title'     => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $base_name ),
            'side'      => isset( $_POST['side_field'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['side_field'] ) : '',
            'key'       => md5( microtime().rand() ),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item;
}

// Display custom cart item data in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_file']['title'] ) ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Logo', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  $cart_item['custom_file']['title']
        );
    }

    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_file']['side'] ) ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __( 'Side', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' =>  $cart_item['custom_file']['side']
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save and display Logo data in orders and email notifications (everywhere)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_field_update_order_item_meta', 20, 4 );
function custom_field_update_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset( $values['custom_file'] ) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Logo'),  $values['custom_file']['title'] );
        $item->update_meta_data( __('Side'),  $values['custom_file']['side'] );
        $item->update_meta_data( '_logo_file_data',  $values['custom_file'] );
    }
}

// Display a linked button + the link of the logo file in backend
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'backend_logo_link_after_order_itemmeta', 20, 3 );
function backend_logo_link_after_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ) {
    // Only in backend for order line items (avoiding errors)
    if( is_admin() && $item->is_type('line_item') && $item->get_meta('_logo_file_data') ){
        $file_data = $item->get_meta( '_logo_file_data' );
        echo '<p><a href="'.$file_data['guid'].'" target="_blank" class="button">'.__("Open Logo") . '</a></p>';
        echo '<p>Link: <textarea type="text" class="input-text" readonly>'.$file_data['guid'].'</textarea></p>';
    }
}
```

This code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

> Tested in Woocommerce version 3.4.x and working with normal products *(from all types)*

---

**Frontend: orders display *(and email notifications)*:**

[image]

**Backend (Admin): Display on orders edit pages:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working perfectly for Single product page. But as I said before I have created a custom page for a client to show products in list view; not only that variable products variation needs to be shown as single product also. I have updated the question, could you please take a look. The site is custom made and uses Woocommerce 2.6

Comment: @NaureenKhan Sorry but I will not go further anymore as I have spent a certain time on this… The problem was related to downoads and know you have everything needed to understand and achieve that yourself. Nobody will help you on that as it's just too broad and very advanced. So you should better accept this answer as it is working and make some new little question, splitting the problem in small parts. Now Woocommerce 2.6 is too Old now and I will not be able to make code for it…

Comment: Thank you. I have marked the Answer. But if you could spare a little time could just take a look at the code and point me out in the right direction.

Comment: @NaureenKhan It's much more complicated as it's for Woocommerce 2.6 (not anymore documented). I can't even test your code on my test servers and I have completely forgotten the way to code before woocommerce 3. Contact me by mail through my stackOverFlow profile.