# Empty Array on first argument for woocommerce_add_cart_item_data filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am getting an empty array from the `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` filter when a product is added to the shopping cart. Example added to `functions.php` of WordPress theme;

```
function TEST_post_filter($a,$b,$c) {

    print_r($a); //THIS IS EMPTY ARRAY ie returns Array()

    return $a;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'Test_post_filter',10,3);
```

Any idea why this might be? I have found no reference to this issue anywhere. I have tried both basket behaviours ie *Redirect to the basket page after successful addition* and/ or *Enable AJAX add to basket buttons on archives*. I can't get my head around it. Plugins I have activated are WooCommerce, and WooCommerce Stripe Gateway.

**UPDATE - Code which adds product options to product screen**

```
    function option_add_to_product() {

        global $product;

        //get pizza categories
        $categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', array(
                'hide_empty' => false,
        ));

        $use_product = [];

        for($i=0;$i<count($categories);$i++) {

            if(strtolower($categories[$i]->slug) === 'bespoke_product')
                array_push($use_product,$categories[$i]->term_id);
        }

       $include_product = false;

        if(! count($use_product))
           return false;

        for($i=0;$i<count($use_product);$i++) {

            $this_product_categories = $product->get_category_ids();

            for($ii=0;$ii<count($this_product_categories);$ii++) {

                if($this_product_categories[$ii] === $use_prouduct[$i]) {
                    $include_product = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(! $include_product)
            return false;

        //template to add product option
        require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/add_product_option.php';
    }
```

You can see the html from *add_product_option.php* will be added to the product if the product has a a category with the slug "bespoke_product". Note, this method of getting a match for a product is temporary (just technical debt for now).

When the filter `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` is called the data posted from the product form is available to the corresponding function. Unsanitised data might read as follows:

```
        [extra_option_one] => 0
        [extra_option_two] => 0
        [extra_options_three] => 1
        [extra_option_four] => 0
        [order_note] =>
```

Each of those options will have a lookup table with a related price e.g. `extra_options_three` might be £1.50. This cost of this option and any others selected needs to up the price of the specific item being added to the cart. It should not be represented separately. The definition of the option added should go into the product field everywhere that purchased item is shown. I'm working through step by step, but it's not easy at the point I am at! I'm guessing the next is tha I'm going to be able to update the item in this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` hook **is used to add custom data to the cart item** on simple add to cart submission, **like additional fields** included in the `<form>` where "add to cart" button is located…

So **if you are not submitting extra custom data** from custom fields on add to cart event on (from single product pages), **the first function argument is going to be an empty array**…

See [those related answer threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=woocommerce_add_cart_item_data) using this hook.

Comment: Thx. I am adding custom data. I guess the next step is to add it to this array and return it? Does the data form part of the product being added to the cart?

Comment: @dewd The default WooCommerce  product data is added to cart, but not the custom data… For the custom data, you will use `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` to include your custom data to the cart item, and the returned argument will be an array of your custom data. See this recent answer simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56221304/3730754… May be you should include your real related code, giving us something testable, to give you some useful feed back.

Comment: I have update the question to include the data posted to the `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data ` filter.

Comment: please don't expand on your answer I have found how to do it, and will post the answer later.

Comment: @dewd Anyways my actual answer was correct with your provided initial question and on your edit you didn't provide the template `add_product_option.php`, so it wasn't testable.

Comment: 100% understood. Thx!